# Can't get order object in sales_order_place_after observer method in multi-shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

Hi guys i am working in magento 1.14 enterprise. i am trying to get order id after order place in multishipping checkout for that i am using this event

> sales_order_place_after

i also tried this one as well

> checkout_submit_all_after

but i am getting nothing in this event i want to get order id

here is my code for config

```
        <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>afterPlaceOrder</method>
            </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
```

and this code for function

```
 public function afterPlaceOrder($observer) {
    $helper = Mage::helper('marketplace');
    $lastOrderId = $observer->getOrder()->getId();

}
```

Its giving me error in this line **Call to a member function getId() to null** can anyone please tell me what i am missing why my observer is giving me nothing i have checked the same scenario in onepage and its working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

I am Not sure  about `sales_order_place_after` event.

But **`checkout_submit_all_after`** is always fire for ***multi shipping checkout*** .

But there are ***some logic change*** at ***parameters***  **default checkout onepage** and ***multi shipping checkout's***  **`checkout_submit_all_after`** event.

### multi shipping checkout

For ***multi shipping checkout's***  ,you goto two parameters at observer.

First one is ***`Orderids of your checkout`*** by `$observer->getEvent()->getOrders()`

Second,one is ***`quote object of your checkout`*** by `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()`

**see:**

[**`Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_submit_all_after', array('orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $this->getQuote()));`**](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php#L536)

### Default onepage checkout

*Getting 3 parameters:*

- Order object of current place order : by
  `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()`
- Quote object of current place order : by
  `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()`
- recurring profilesobject of current place order by
  `$observer->getEvent()->getRecurringProfiles()`

See at:

[***`Mage::dispatchEvent(
       'checkout_submit_all_after',
        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'recurring_profiles' => $profiles)
    );`***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php#L870)

**So there are  some logical changes are need at your observer**